# Django mod_wsgi: ImportError: No module named 'home'

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I have a Django project that runs without issue using the dev server (runserver), but fails when serving through Apache/WSGI.

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Python 3.5.2
- Django 2.0.4
- mod_wsgi 4.6.4

The error is `ImportError: No module named 'home'` and here's the trace from Apache's error log:

```
[Thu May 03 19:01:11.010623 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 8568:tid 139727981401984] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/3.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 03 19:01:11.010742 2018] [mpm_event:info] [pid 8568:tid 139727981401984] AH00490: Server built: 2018-04-18T14:53:04
[Thu May 03 19:01:11.010763 2018] [core:notice] [pid 8568:tid 139727981401984] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu May 03 19:01:11.011684 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 8572:tid 139727981401984] mod_wsgi (pid=8572): Python home /home/xxx/is_websites/webenv/.
[Thu May 03 19:01:11.011766 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 8572:tid 139727981401984] mod_wsgi (pid=8572): Initializing Python.
[Thu May 03 19:01:11.014159 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 8571:tid 139727981401984] mod_wsgi (pid=8571): Python home /home/xxx/is_websites/webenv/.
[Thu May 03 19:01:11.014238 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 8571:tid 139727981401984] mod_wsgi (pid=8571): Initializing Python.
[Thu May 03 19:01:11.052639 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 8572:tid 139727981401984] mod_wsgi (pid=8572): Attach interpreter ''.
[Thu May 03 19:01:11.054513 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 8571:tid 139727981401984] mod_wsgi (pid=8571): Attach interpreter ''.
[Thu May 03 19:01:11.073009 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 8571:tid 139727981401984] mod_wsgi (pid=8571): Adding '/home/xxx/is_websites/' to path.
[Thu May 03 19:01:11.075298 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 8572:tid 139727981401984] mod_wsgi (pid=8572): Adding '/home/xxx/is_websites/' to path.
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.330027 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] mod_wsgi (pid=8572): Create interpreter '127.0.1.1|'.
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.346866 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] mod_wsgi (pid=8572): Adding '/home/xxx/is_websites/' to path.
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.347805 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_wsgi (pid=8572, process='', application='127.0.1.1|'): Loading Python script file '/home/xxx/is_websi$
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.665257 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_wsgi (pid=8572): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/xxx/is_websites/is_spa/is_spa/wsgi.py'.
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.665326 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_wsgi (pid=8572): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/xxx/is_websites/is_spa/is_spa/wsgi$
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.667315 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.667375 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/home/xxx/is_websites/is_spa/is_spa/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.667386 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.667399 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/home/xxx/is_websites/webenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_w$
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.667405 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.667416 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/home/xxx/is_websites/webenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.667422 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.667432 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/home/xxx/is_websites/webenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in p$
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.667439 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.667449 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/home/xxx/is_websites/webenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in cre$
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.667455 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     module = import_module(entry)
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.667465 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/home/xxx/is_websites/webenv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.667471 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.667481 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.667493 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.667504 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Thu May 03 19:01:23.667539 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8572:tid 139727768385280] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] ImportError: No module named 'home'
```

It seems like the error is in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`, which looks for a `home` app.

I can't find any issue with the Django files. I have a `home` app with an `__init__.py` file, and everything works on the dev server.

This makes me think it might be a `mod_wsgi` issue, so I reinstalled mod_wsgi to make sure I installed against the correct python version from my virtualenv, and I changed group ownership recursively to `www-data` to make sure I don't have permission issues.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple... but I don't see it!

## Update 1

Here's the apache virtual host setup:

```
LogLevel info

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/xxx/is_websites/is_spa/is_spa/wsgi.py

WSGIDaemonProcess xxx_website processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup xxx_website

<Directory /home/xxx/is_websites/is_spa/is_spa/>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Here is apache mod `wsgi.load`:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Here is apache mod `wsgi.conf`:

```
WSGIPythonHome /home/xxx/is_websites/webenv/
WSGIPythonPath /home/xxx/is_websites/is_spa/
```

As requested, here's what I get when manually importing `home`:

```
(webenv) xxx@django-wagtail-postgres:~/is_websites/is_spa$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import home
>>> home.__file__
'/home/xxx/is_websites/is_spa/home/__init__.py'
>>>
```

And here's the output from wsgi `make install`:

```
(webenv) root@django-wagtail-postgres:/home/xxx/mod_wsgi-4.6.4# make install                                                                                                                                         
/usr/bin/apxs2 -i -S LIBEXECDIR=/usr/lib/apache2/modules -n 'mod_wsgi' src/server/mod_wsgi.la                                                                                                                        
/usr/share/apache2/build/instdso.sh SH_LIBTOOL='/usr/share/apr-1.0/build/libtool' src/server/mod_wsgi.la /usr/lib/apache2/modules                                                                                    
/usr/share/apr-1.0/build/libtool --mode=install install src/server/mod_wsgi.la /usr/lib/apache2/modules/                                                                                                             
libtool: install: install src/server/.libs/mod_wsgi.so /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so                                                                                                                          
libtool: install: install src/server/.libs/mod_wsgi.lai /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.la                                                                                                                         
libtool: finish: PATH="/home/xxx/is_websites/webenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/lib/apache2/modules                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                               
Libraries have been installed in:                                                                                                                                                                                    
   /usr/lib/apache2/modules                                                                                                                                                                                          

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries                                                                                                                                                       
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and                                                                                                                                                       
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'                                                                                                                                                      
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:                                                                                                                                                            
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable                                                                                                                                                        
     during execution                                                                                                                                                                                                
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable                                                                                                                                                            
     during linking                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag                                                                                                                                                                     
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'                                                                                                                                                  

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for                                                                                                                                                    
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.                                                                                                                                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                               
chmod 644 /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so                                                                                                                                                                       
(webenv) root@django-wagtail-postgres:/home/xxx/mod_wsgi-4.6.4#
```

## Update 2

I added Python-path to the Damon process as instructed (as well as python-home):
`WSGIDaemonProcess website processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/home/xxx/is_websites/webenv/ python-path=/home/xxx/is_websites/is_spa`

But I still get an error. This time `ImportError: No module named 'is_spa.is_spa'`

```
[Mon May 07 14:39:15.769405 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 3693:tid 140405951944576] mod_wsgi (pid=3693): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Mon May 07 14:39:15.771668 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 3692:tid 140405951944576] mod_wsgi (pid=3692): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Mon May 07 14:39:15.785445 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 3693:tid 140405951944576] mod_wsgi (pid=3693): Terminating Python.
[Mon May 07 14:39:15.786996 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 3692:tid 140405951944576] mod_wsgi (pid=3692): Terminating Python.
[Mon May 07 14:39:15.801152 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 3693:tid 140405951944576] mod_wsgi (pid=3693): Python has shutdown.
[Mon May 07 14:39:15.801201 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 3693:tid 140405951944576] mod_wsgi (pid=3693): Exiting process 'website'.
[Mon May 07 14:39:15.802813 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 3692:tid 140405951944576] mod_wsgi (pid=3692): Python has shutdown.
[Mon May 07 14:39:15.802837 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 3692:tid 140405951944576] mod_wsgi (pid=3692): Exiting process 'website'.
[Mon May 07 14:39:16.736463 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3926:tid 140137508214656] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/3.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon May 07 14:39:16.736597 2018] [core:notice] [pid 3926:tid 140137508214656] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon May 07 14:39:16.827772 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 3929:tid 140137508214656] mod_wsgi (pid=3929): Attach interpreter ''.
[Mon May 07 14:39:16.832887 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 3928:tid 140137508214656] mod_wsgi (pid=3928): Attach interpreter ''.
[Mon May 07 14:39:16.871324 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 3929:tid 140137508214656] mod_wsgi (pid=3929): Adding '/home/xxx/is_websites/is_spa' to path.
[Mon May 07 14:39:16.876253 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 3928:tid 140137508214656] mod_wsgi (pid=3928): Adding '/home/xxx/is_websites/is_spa' to path.
[Mon May 07 14:39:19.891511 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] mod_wsgi (pid=3929): Create interpreter '127.0.1.1|'.
[Mon May 07 14:39:19.908227 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] mod_wsgi (pid=3929): Adding '/home/xxx/is_websites/is_spa' to path.
[Mon May 07 14:39:19.909016 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_wsgi (pid=3929, process='website', application='127.0.1.1|'): Loading Python script file '/home/xxx/is_websites/is_spa/is_spa/wsgi.py'.
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.262585 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_wsgi (pid=3929): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/xxx/is_websites/is_spa/is_spa/wsgi.py'.
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.262676 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_wsgi (pid=3929): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/xxx/is_websites/is_spa/is_spa/wsgi.py'.
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263610 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263692 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/home/xxx/is_websites/is_spa/is_spa/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263702 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263715 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/home/xxx/is_websites/webenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263721 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263732 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/home/xxx/is_websites/webenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263738 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263749 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/home/xxx/is_websites/webenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263755 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     self._setup(name)
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263765 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/home/xxx/is_websites/webenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263783 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263795 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/home/xxx/is_websites/webenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263801 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263811 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/home/xxx/is_websites/webenv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263818 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263828 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263840 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263851 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263863 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263875 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263886 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263898 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263909 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263921 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263932 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263944 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon May 07 14:39:20.263970 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3929:tid 140137402570496] [remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] ImportError: No module named 'is_spa.is_spa'
```

But the `is_spa` module is there:

```
(webenv) xxx@django-wagtail-postgres:~/is_websites/is_spa$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import is_spa
>>> is_spa.__file__
'/home/wag/is_websites/is_spa/is_spa/__init__.py'
>>>
```

Is there a particular location that the script must be located in a Django project? My folder structure is `/is_spa/is_spa/`, where the first directory is the project, and the second is the app. I currently have the WSGI script in the app directory, but I can't imagine that would matter when we explicitly set the `python-path` option.

Comment: What is the configuration you used for mod_wsgi? If you import ``home`` manually some how, or add debug to your code to print it, what do you get for ``home.__file__``? BTW, is better to use daemon mode.

Comment: I answered your questions under the heading Update 1. Thanks for the help @GrahamDumpleton !

Comment: Try adding ``python-path=/home/xxx/is_websites/is_spa`` option to ``WSGIDaemonProcess``, I can't remember but don't think ``WSGIPythonPath`` is inherited by ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` process.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I added another update (2) above after setting the `python-path` option

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, that fixed it! In addition to the `python-path` issue, I had to change the WSGI script to point to the correct settings path. (I had monkeyed with it while troubleshooting and forgot to change it back.) Thanks so much for the help! :-)

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton if you would like to write an answer (or copy mine below) I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is that the WSGIDamonProcess needs the `python-path` to be set explicitly in it's options. It does not inherit the global value.

As @GrahamDumpleton pointed out, changing

`WSGIDaemonProcess website processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}`

to

`WSGIDaemonProcess website processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/home/xxx/is_websites/is_spa`

solved the issue.